# Git merge "Already up-to-date" only when commits are the same

Tags: git, version-control, merge

This is the scenario: I have a develop branch from which I create new branches to add new features:

```
git checkout -b newfeature develop
```

After I completed the changes in newfeature, I checkout back to develop and try to merge the new changes (I use --no-ff because I want the merge to always create a commit object):

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff newfeature
```

And I get the following result: `Already up-to-date.`. I've read other questions at stackoverflow and I understand that this is not possible because `newfeature` is a parent of `develop`, but why develop has the changes of `newfeature` automatically without merging?

Also, I tried to add a commit to `newfeature` and merged back to `develop`, and this time it worked; it created two commits on `develop` branch, one for merging and the other is the same as the commit of `newfeature`.

I'm a little bit confused, could you guysclear my doubts?

Answer (score 0):

You can only merge "commits", that is your second case. You cannot merge the changes you made to files when you were on `newfeature` branch.

i.e.
You are on `newfeature` branch and you do changes to your files but don't commit.
Then you go to `develop` branch and try to merge changes from `newfeature` this will do nothing as there is no commit on `newfeature`.

Comment: So should I always commit to newfeature before merging back to develop or there is some other way to accomplish the same result?

Comment: yes you will have to commit in `newfeature` or if you want to commit from `develop` but you have done changes in `newfeature` you can stash them and apply stash in develop. Go through the `git stash`  command.